# Python: How to detect debug interpreter

Tags: python, debugging

How can I detect in my python script if its being run by the debug interpreter (ie python_d.exe rather than python.exe)? I need to change the paths to some dlls that I pass to an extension.

eg Id like to do something like this at the start of my python script:

```
#get paths to graphics dlls
if debug_build:
    d3d9Path   = "bin\\debug\\direct3d9.dll"
    d3d10Path  = "bin\\debug\\direct3d10.dll"
    openGLPath = "bin\\debug\\openGL2.dll"
else:
    d3d9Path   = "bin\\direct3d9.dll"
    d3d10Path  = "bin\\direct3d10.dll"
    openGLPath = "bin\\openGL2.dll"
```

I thought about adding an "IsDebug()" method to the extension which would return true if it is the debug build (ie was built with "#define DEBUG") and false otherwise. But this seems a bit of a hack for somthing Im sure I can get python to tell me...

Comment: Have you considered using raw strings to avoid excess escaping? r'bin\debug\direct3d9.dll'

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Distutils use `sys.gettotalrefcount` to detect a debug python build](http://bugs.python.org/file2086/build.py.diff):

```
# ...
if hasattr(sys, 'gettotalrefcount'):
   plat_specifier += '-pydebug'
```

- this method doesn't rely on an executable name '`*_d.exe`'. It works for any name.
- this method is cross-platform. It doesn't depend on '`_d.pyd`' suffix.

See [Debugging Builds](http://docs.python.org/c-api/intro.html#debugging-builds) and [Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Misc/SpecialBuilds.txt?view=markup)

Comment: This is an old answer, but I'm a person from the future here to confirm that this still works fine on Python 3.7.1.

Comment: Here is an example one-liner:
```python -c "import sys; sys.exit(int(hasattr(sys, 'gettotalrefcount')))" # returns 0 if is a non-debug build, 1 if is a debug build
```
Here is a bash test:
```if [[ python -c "import sys; sys.exit(int(hasattr(sys, 'gettotalrefcount')))" ]]; then
        PYTHON_DEBUG= ;
    else:
        PYTHON_DEBUG="y"
    fi
```

Comment: sorry remove the square brackets in the bash example to have it working

Answer (score 3):

Better, because it also works when you are running an embedded Python interpreter is to check the return value of

```
imp.get_suffixes()
```

For a debug build it contains a tuple starting with '_d.pyd':

```
# debug build:
[('_d.pyd', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyw', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]

# release build:
[('.pyd', 'rb', 3), ('.py', 'U', 1), ('.pyw', 'U', 1), ('.pyc', 'rb', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

An easy way, if you don't mind relying on the file name:

```
if sys.executable.endswith("_d.exe"):
  print "running on debug interpreter"
```

You can read more about the `sys` module and its various facilities [here](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html).