# How do I check if the python debug option is set from within a script

Tags: python, script-debugging

If I'm in debug mode, I want to do other stuff than when I'm not.

```
if DEBUG:
    STORED_DATA_FILE = os.path.join(TEMP_DIR, 'store.dat')
    LOG_LEVEL = logging.DEBUG
    print "debug mode"
else:
    STORED_DATA_FILE = os.path.join(SCRIPT_PATH, 'store.dat')
    LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
    print "not debug mode"
```

then:

```
python script.py
not debug mode

python -d script.py
debug mode
```

How can I detect that? It certainly isn't using the `__debug__` variable.

Comment: Well to clarify for the questions below. All I really want to do is pick up some information from the general environment, but I tried setting an environment variable and looking for it in os.environ but that does not always work.

Comment: unrelated to `-d` option: [Python: How to detect debug interpreter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646518/python-how-to-detect-debug-interpreter)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27748132/is-there-a-flag-i-can-check-in-my-code-to-see-if-pycharms-debugger-is-running?answertab=active#tab-top

This answer work for me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Parser debug mode is enabled with `-d` commandline option or PYTHONDEBUG environment variable and starting from python 2.6 is reflected in `sys.flags.debug`. But are you sure this is what you are looking for?

Comment: That works for 2.6 and above, thanks. Now if anyone has an answer for 2.5 and below?

Answer (score 14):

you can use `python -O` with the `__debug__` variable

where `-O` means optimise. so `__debug__` is false

`-d` turns on debugging for the parser, which is not what you want

Comment: yes , -O continuously monitors the script and don't even need to reload