# Python create __init__.py to point to right subpackage

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I want to achieve something odd I guess. Basically, I have a working implementation of my app. Now I want to change one of my app packages entirely. But I want at least for now leave the old implementation in place, to still use it in production.

I've created a sample project to reproduce the problem I have.

Let's say I have a dir structure like this:

```
│   setup.py
│
└───foo
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───foo1
        │   foo1_module.py
        │   __init__.py
        │
        └───foo2
                foo2_module.py
                __init__.py
```

What I want to do is to change the implementation of `foo1` entirely. I want to apply the changes gradually and still have the old implementation being used.

So I moved the contents of `foo/foo1` to `foo/foo1/old`. Then I want to create a `foo/foo1/new` directory and implement the changes in there:

```
│   setup.py
│
└───foo
    │   __init__.py
    │
    └───foo1
        │   __init__.py
        │
        └───old
            │   foo1_module.py
            │   __init__.py
            │
            └───foo2
                    foo2_module.py
                    __init__.py
```

The thing is, I don't want to change other packages' imports in my code.

So if an import looks like this: `from foo.foo1.foo1_module import func` - I want it to stay like this, without having to change it to `from from foo.foo1.old.foo1_module import func`.

Therefore, I put this in `foo/foo1/__init__.py`:

```py
from .old import *
```

Then I wanted to test it:

foo\foo1\old\foo1_module.py:

```py
def func():
    pass
```

foo\foo1\old\foo2\foo2_module.py:

```
from foo.foo1.foo1_module import func
```

```
  File "e:\projects\python\imports\foo\foo1\old\foo2\foo2_module.py", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.foo1.foo1_module import func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo.foo1.foo1_module'
```

So the question is: can I somehow get the `foo/foo1/__init__.py` to, I don't know, point to/import the things from the `foo/foo1/old`, so for everyone importing this, the import paths would stay the same?

Cuz if not, I am left with two options:

- either add the `.old.` part in every absolute import
- rearrange my package, so there are no parent package imports (like in `foo2_module.py`) and then use relateive `from .` imports

Comment: This sounds somewhat like "how do I set a debug flag for all modules and sub-modules?" to me. From there you could decide at each "\_\_init__" what to do in case of "debug" mode. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27455446/3220135) answer on how to do that. Also see the python [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#__debug__)

Comment: Hm, okay. I get the idea here, but the thing is, this example thing that I created is small. I would have to apply this `if` statement to one import and it's done. However, if I had to do this in my project, I would have to double the amount of imports from the package (which amount is like 50+, so it would be way over 100) and put them in `if/else` blocks. Don't know if that's the best solution here. It would be perfect if I could apply something like this only in my `__init__` file. But maybe that's what you meant and I just couldn't make it work

Comment: Additionally, the `__debug__` flag wouldn't suffice here - I still would want to run my application (it's running in real time), make the changes in a certain amount of time and replace the old implementation with a new one with a single move