# ImportError when executing Python indirectly (With s Subprocess from PHP in My Case)

Tags: php, python, subprocess, environment-variables, importerror

When I attempt to execute a Python script I have, which (if it's relevant) is importing `pymssql`, I get the error:
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "./assets/bin/invoices", line 4, in import pymssql as db ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pymssql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _iconv Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib Expected in: /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/libiconv.2.dylib in /usr/local/lib/libsybdb.5.dylib`

I'm attempting to execute it using `shell_exec`, after explicitly setting the environment variables PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to match their values when queried from the shell. Does anyone know why this is happening, and/or how to make it work as expected?  This has stumped me for day.

Comment: Did you get this script working on your system (that is, w/o the PHP wrapper) or did you never try?

Comment: It does work without the wrapper, yes

Comment: Do you have more than one python distribution? Maybe you are calling a different python interpreter (or there is a release/debug difference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646518/python-how-to-detect-debug-interpreter )... For further debugging, at the beginning of your script you can print sys.path , os.environ['PATH'] etc and compare differences between the execution in the shell or form exec

Comment: I have ensured that I am invoking Python2.7. I should also note that when deployed to a CentOS server, it does work as expected.  The problem is on a MacOS system.  Mavericks, specifically.